# Spark 2.4.7 JDBC hive query SQLException:Method not supported

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive, methodnotfound

Using spark shell 2.2.1 hive JDBC I could query table. Below are details
Spark - 2.2.1
MAPR - 6.0.1
JDBC query - `spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:hive2://test.server.com:10000/default;ssl=true).option("dbtable","MyTable").option("user","testuser").("password","testuserpassword").option("driver","org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").load().show()`

Result - Above works

Spark - 2.4.7
MAPR - 6.2
JDBC query - Same as above
Result - This throws - SQLException:Method not supported

Can someone please help?